# In Django DRF I always get the ValueError in my update method in my serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-serializer

I am using Django DRF and I have successfully created the create method in my serializer but somehow the update method doesn't want to work as I want.
I always get the same ValueError.

**My Model:**

```
class User(models.Model):
gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER, default='Male')
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
position = models.CharField(max_length=50)
birthday = models.DateField(auto_created=False, null=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
password = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)


class Company(models.Model):
company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
zip = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=False)


class PartnerCompany(models.Model):
partner = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
contact_person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**My Serializer**

```
class PartnerCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
partner = CompanySerializer(many=False)
contact_person = ClientUserSerializer(many=False)

class Meta:
    model = PartnerCompany
    fields = '__all__'

def create(self, validated_data):
    partner = validated_data.pop('partner')
    contact_person = validated_data.pop('contact_person')
    partner_instance = Company.objects.create(**partner)
    contact_person_instance = User.objects.create(**contact_person)
    return PartnerCompany.objects.create(partner=partner_instance,
                                         contact_person=contact_person_instance,
                                         **validated_data)


def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.partner = validated_data.get('partner', instance.partner)
    instance.contact_person = validated_data.get('contact_person', instance.contact_person)
    partner_instance = Company.objects.update(**instance.partner)
    instance.save(partner_instance)
    return instance
```

My View:

```
class PartnerCompanyUpdateByID(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
lookup_field = 'id'
queryset = PartnerCompany.objects.all()
serializer_class = PartnerCompanySerializer
```

I always get this ValueError:

> ValueError at /partner/update/id/6
>   Cannot assign "OrderedDict([('company_name', 'UBS Switzerland'), ('address', 'Mainstreet 1'), ('zip', 4102), ('city', 'Basel'), ('email', 'ubs@ubs.ch')])": "PartnerCompany.partner" must be a "Company" instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't send **partner_instance** as a parameter in `instance.save()`. **instance** already has the new values in **partner**.

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.partner = validated_data.get('partner', instance.partner)
    instance.contact_person = validated_data.get('contact_person', instance.contact_person)
    partner_instance = Company.objects.update(**instance.partner)
    instance.partner = partner_instance
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Comment: I still get the same ValueError, in fact i have been trying to debug and for that reason it was still as a parameter in instance.save()

Comment: Great! You're welcome. I'll appreciate you to select my answer

Comment: This solution is working but it is creating a new record in the DB. However, i only need to update the existing entry. Is there a workaround for this

Comment: Do you mean a new record of **PartnerCompany**?

Comment: indeed, it adds a complete new record of PartnerCompany in the db. However, for some reason the code above worked for a couple of inserts and now the same ERR shows up that ""PartnerCompany.partner" must be a "Company" instance."

Comment: That's weird. The only explanation that I have, is that you get that error when `Company.objects.update(**instance.partner)` fails, so you get `partner_instance=None`, or something like that. There's no possible way that it works in some cases and in some other it doesn't

Comment: strange indeed! However, i am using 3rd party package "drf-writable-nested" it solves the problem I am having. Although it still does not patch/update the exisiting record but it ads a complete new record to the db. I will need to add more logic to avoid this. Thanks for the support!